# Can only send 1 unit for Combat Deployment

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I remember being able to send 2 units for Combat Deployment before, but suddenly, when opening iDroid, I was kinda forced to do tutorial-ish stuff about Combat Deployment... forcing me to send a unit for some sort of VIP Guard Duty...

Kinda weird for the tutorial to appear now when the feature was unlocked quite a while before.

And here comes the problem. After the forced tutorial-thingy, I can no longer send a second unit in Combat Deployment.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that your combat team has enough people in it?

Comment: @MrScapgrace, yeph... just checked that I got full choke of dudes (65/65) in that department... never a fan of wasting human resource so I always try my best to kidnap those poor soldiers...

Answer (score 1):

err... I'm quite sure of what happened, but it seems the forced tutorial-ish "VIP Guard Duty" deployment actually still going on, and never finished even after playing for roughly 7 hours... plus said "VIP Guard Duty" deployment didn't appear among the deployment list.

A friend just told me that I can abort ALL ongoing deployments by using square button while on deployment list screen and viola... the unit which stuck in that forced tutorial can now be used again...

weird... case closed I guess...